# I would like to respond to member information in node express api

Tags: node.js

Hello I have a question

res.send is not work at below code

how to send req.body using res.send?

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("member register request check");
        console.log("req.body : ", req.body);
        res.send('member info : ',req.body) 
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

server console

```
req.body :  { userId: 'tere', password: '1234', nickname: 'te' }
```

error:

```
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: member register request check
```

Comment: I think the issue might be that you are passing two parameters to the `.send()` function. Try to pass a single variable to that function.

Comment: res.send(req.body.userId)  it's not work but error is disappeared

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying either of the two approaches below:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("member register request check");
        console.log("req.body : ", req.body);
        res.send('member info : ' + req.body);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

or

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("member register request check");
        console.log("req.body : ", req.body);
        res.json({ memberInfo: req.body }); 
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no error in the way you told me, but there is no output

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            console.log("member register request check");
            console.log("req.body : ", req.body);
            res.send(req.body) 
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

Basically `req.body` would be JSON

Comment: error is disappeared but it's not output but thanks for advice

Comment: can you please show me the output of  `console.log(req.body)` ?

Comment: req.body :  { userId: 'tere', password: '1234', nickname: 'te' }

Comment: I reproduced the codes but it works as expected. Please check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/zaw-hlaing-bwar/ef11cd226d4d193430d4beaf5d6a4e2d)